# Simplify Complex double Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve below integral. However, when I am calculating the denominator integral, its value is infinite. Is there any way to simplify this before doing integral (maybe some terms would be cancelled out so I can get rid of that infinity :D)
$$I=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}dxdy}{\displaystyle a+b\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{g(x,y)}dxdy}$$
$a$, and $b$ are real and positive. $f(x,y)=e^{ix+iy}$ and $g(x,y)$ is a polynomial. Let me know if you need further information.

Thanks,

Comment: You could try to change the integrand like Polyakov did, when he calculated the Wilson loop, i.e. $\epsilon +g(x,y)$ and then extract the divergent term.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately, I am not familiar with this, can you advise me on some reference for that?

Comment: Polyakov, Gauge fields as rings of glue,  Nuclear Physics B164 (1979) 171-188. Starting from eq. 4.1.